# Suavidade na transição de um menu Sticky

Tags: jquery, css, animação

Criei um menu sticky, funciona perfeitamente, porém a transição não é suave, como faço pra adicionar?

```
function stick() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 140){  
    $('.header').addClass("sticky");
    $('.logo').addClass("sticky");
    $('.header-menu').addClass("sticky");
    $('.dropdown-content').addClass("sticky");
    $('#mobile-clicker').addClass("sticky");
    $('.hamburguer-img').addClass("sticky");
    $('.active').addClass("sticky");
    $('.active-drop').addClass("sticky");
    $('#searchform').addClass("sticky");
    $('.search-formulario').addClass("sticky");
} else {
    $('.header').removeClass("sticky");
    $('.logo').removeClass("sticky");
    $('.header-menu').removeClass("sticky");
    $('.dropdown-content').removeClass("sticky");
    $('#mobile-clicker').removeClass("sticky");
    $('.hamburguer-img').removeClass("sticky");
    $('.active').removeClass("sticky");
    $('.active-drop').removeClass("sticky");
    $('#searchform').removeClass("sticky");
    $('.search-formulario').removeClass("sticky");
}
```

}

Comment: Procure utilizar animações/transições CSS invés de javascript/jquery.

Comment: Ui... que confusão que para aí vai. É um pouco complicado dizer ao certo o que está originando este problema sem ver um exemplo. Adicione um exemplo ou tente recriá-lo num [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) e tente detalhar melhor qual é o problema da transição.